# Scanner Object giving me error in While loop

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I am having a small issue with getting this program to run properly.

```
/**
 *
 * @author Randy
 */
import java.util.Scanner;//Import scanner

public class RandyGilmanhw2a {
    int year_of_birth;
    int age;

    public RandyGilmanhw2a (){//begin constructor
        year_of_birth = 1900;
        age = 0;
    }//end constructor

    public int getYear(){//get year method
        return year_of_birth;
    }//end method

    public int getAge(int year_of_birth){//get year method
        age = 2014 - year_of_birth;
    return age;
    }//end get year method

    public void setYear (int year){//set year method
        this.year_of_birth = year;
    }//end method

    public static void main(String[] args) {//begin main

        RandyGilmanhw2a user1 = new RandyGilmanhw2a();

        Scanner year = new Scanner(System.in);//create a scanner object
        System.out.println("Please enter the year you were born: ");
        int year_of_birth = year.nextInt();

        while( year_of_birth < 1900 || year_of_birth > 2014 ) {//begin while loop
            System.out.println("Please reenter the year you were born." );
            System.out.println("You must have an integer between 1900 and 2014:" );
            System.out.println("\n");

            System.out.println("Please enter the year you were born: ");
            int year_of_birth = year.nextInt();//ERROR OCCURS HERE SAYS VARIABLE
            //year_of_birth ALREADY DEFINED IN METHOD MAIN
        }//end while 

        user1.getAge(year_of_birth);
        System.out.println("You are " + age + " years old." );//ERROR HERE SAYS NON-STATIC
        // VARIABLE age CANNOT BE REFERENCED FROM A STAIC CONTEXT

    }//end main

}//end class
```

I have commented on the areas that are displaying the error. I am trying to make a program that displays the age of a person by them entering there age. However, if they enter a year before 1900 or after 2014, I want it to ask the user to reenter their year of birth. I can't seem to find the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the `int` declaration. That way, you're redifining the variable.
So, switch this:

```
int year_of_birth = year.nextInt();
```

to this:

```
year_of_birth = year.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove `int`  at `int year_of_birth = year.nextInt();` and change age output to this:

```
System.out.println("You are " + user1.getAge(year_of_birth) + " years old." );
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `int` from the second initialization of `year_of_birth` and your problem should go away.

Answer (score 1):

Don't define `year_of_birth` as `int` again in while loop as you have defined in out of loop.

```
 while( year_of_birth < 1900 || year_of_birth > 2014 ) {//begin while loop
        ...
        year_of_birth = year.nextInt();//just assign next value
        ...
    }
```